# Both image and label in menu

Tags: python, image, tkinter, label, menubar

I am trying to add icons to commands in tkinter menu bar. I used this code to add images:

```
file_menu.add_command(label="Create new project", image=icons["new"], command=new_project)
```

but it resulted in this:

[image: Result image]

How do I show both an image and a label?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The menu or any label takes in an argument called `compound`

```
file_menu.add_command(label="Create new project", image=icons["new"],compound = LEFT, command=new_project)
```

here `LEFT` is from `tkinter` package and is for alignment. It is used to indicate as to which side the image has to be placed.

NOTE: If you have used `import tkinter` then you will have to write `compound = tkinter.LEFT`